# Display filenames beginning with the letter t

Tags: perl

anyone know how to display long listing of the /etc dir whose filenames begins with the letter t and then print the filename column, indicating what you are printing?

```
Example) perl.pl
/etc
filename: terminfo
filename: fruit 
filename: time
filename: birds
```

Comment: I don't understand. `fruit` doesn't begin with `t`. Please show the Perl code that you're having problems with

Comment: Nevermind borodin, and I wrote the question wrong sorry. Each word in the output is supposed to begin with t.

Comment: I found out how to do it by looking at my notes :) You can also use awk

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name 't*'
```

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name 't*' -type f        # Plain files only
```

```
find /etc -name 't*' -type f                    # Recursive search
```

From within Perl, this functionality is provided by [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule).

```
say for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->name('t*')->in('/etc');
```

```
say for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->name('t*')->file->in('/etc');
```

```
say for File::Find::Rule->name('t*')->file->in('/etc');
```

Comment: What about `find2perl` ?

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, If you have an exiting command you want to convert, you can try it. But you'll get far cleaner results doing the simple translation to File::Find::Rule manually.

Comment: ...unless you have different actions for different conditions. In that case, you might have to use the less clean File::Find module, and you might find some benefit in using `find2perl` if you have an existing command.